# Could I make this Haskell more idiomatic?

Tags: haskell, idioms

I'm working on the HackerRank problem sets. The following Haskell correctly solves the problem, but I have a hunch that it's not what a seasoned veteran would write. I'd appreciate any input on how to make this prettier/more expressive.

```
compTrips :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
compTrips as bs =
  let oneIfGreater a b = if a > b
                         then 1
                         else 0
      countGreater x y = foldr (+) 0 $ zipWith oneIfGreater x y
   in [countGreater as bs, countGreater bs as]

main = do
  line1 <- getLine
  line2 <- getLine
  let alice = map read $ words line1
  let bob = map read $ words line2
  let (a:b:_) = compTrips alice bob
  putStrLn $ show a ++ " " ++ show b
```

Comment: The code review site might be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: One problem: if the user enters bad input, your program will crash. Better: import `Text.Read` and use `readMaybe` with `traverse`. On error, throw a proper `IO` exception using `Control.Exception.throwIO`.

Comment: @dfeuer I'll wait for my 40 minutes to pass and cross-post. (SO has grown a LOT since I last used it!)

I understand your feedback about making the code more resilient. The problem statement, however, guarantees that the input will be sanitized, so I'm wondering more about style.

Comment: `foldr (+) 0` is just `sum`. But you can make use of `length (filter (...))`. Furthermore you better use a 2-tuple if you return two values, since then the types can be hetrogenous, and furthermore by the type signature (and by compiler checks) you specify it will *always* return 2 values.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like `compTrips`'s type; it's too permissive. Declaring that it can return an `[Int]` says you don't know how many `Int`s it will return. But you know it will be exactly two; so:

```
compTrips :: [Int] -> [Int] -> (Int, Int)
```

In the implementation, I'd prefer `sum` to `foldr (+) 0`; it says more clearly what you intend, and also, as a side benefit, `sum` uses a strict left fold and so sometimes can be more memory-efficient:

```
compTrips as bs =
  let oneIfGreater a b = if a > b
                         then 1
                         else 0
      countGreater x y = sum $ zipWith oneIfGreater x y
   in (countGreater as bs, countGreater bs as)
```

I don't like that we compute each comparison twice. I'd want to split out the computation of the comparison from the counting up of which way the comparison went. At the same time, I would switch over from using `sum` and your custom `fromEnum` implementation (namely, `oneIfGreater`) to using a combination of `length` and `filter` (or, in this case where we want both "sides" of the filter, `partition`). So:

```
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.List

compTrips as bs = bimap length length . partition id $ zipWith (>) as bs
```

I think you can abstract the reading and parsing of a line so that this logic is not replicated. So:

```
readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = do
    line <- getLine
    pure (map read $ words line)

main = do
  alice <- readInts
  bob <- readInts
  let (a, b) = compTrips alice bob
  putStrLn $ show a ++ " " ++ show b
```

I don't like `read`'s type, for almost exactly the same reason I don't like `compTrips`'s type. In this case, declaring that it can accept any `String` says it can parse anything, when in reality it can only parse a very specific language. `readMaybe` has a better type, saying that it may sometimes fail to parse:

```
readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

There's a large collection of `Applicative`-based methods for combining the error-handling of many calls to `readMaybe`; especially check out `traverse` (which is a bit like `map`, but with the capability to handle errors) and `liftA2` (which can convert any binary operation into one that can handle errors).

One way we could use it would be to print a nice error message when it failed, so:

```
import System.IO
import Text.Read

readInts = do
  line <- getLine
  case traverse readMaybe (words line) of
    Just person -> pure person
    Nothing -> do
      hPutStrLn stderr "That doesn't look like a space-separated collection of numbers! Try again."
      readInts
```

(Other error-handling options exist.)

That leaves us with the following final program:

```
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.List
import System.IO
import Text.Read

compTrips :: [Int] -> [Int] -> (Int, Int)
compTrips as bs = bimap length length . partition id $ zipWith (>) as bs

readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = do
  line <- getLine
  case traverse readMaybe (words line) of
    Just person -> pure person
    Nothing -> do
      hPutStrLn stderr "That doesn't look like a space-separated collection of numbers! Try again."
      readInts

main :: IO ()
main = do
  alice <- readInts
  bob <- readInts
  let (a, b) = compTrips alice bob
  putStrLn $ show a ++ " " ++ show b
```

Although the text is actually a bit longer, I would consider this a more idiomatic implementation; the main two things being to pay careful attention to avoiding the use of partial functions (like `read` and your partial pattern match on the result of `compTrips`) and increasing the reliance on library-provided bulk operations when handling lists (like our use of `length` and `partition`).

Comment: Thank you. I can see why a Galois employee "wouldn't like" these constructs. Let me bang my head against your version until I get some intuition about it.

Comment: @cyclotropic, `bimap length length` here is bad. Better to use facilities from the `foldl` package.

Comment: Very minor point: the original code counted the `<` cases and the `>` cases, ignoring the `==` cases. The code above uses `partition`, so the `==` cases get counted (AFAICS, together with the `<` cases). That was probably a bug in the original code.

Comment: My tolerance for combinators is higher than most; I'd like to use `whenNothing(M)` in `readInts`. Also I prefer `<>` over `++` for `String` because the fact that it's actually `[Char]` feels like an implementation detail, albeit one that's everyone's comfortable & familiar with. Easier to swap to `Text` later when your program grows too!

Comment: @chi Major point: you didn't read entirety of my original post.

Comment: @dfeuer Such as?

Comment: Big picture, you're encouraging more specificity when talking about data and types. Any hints about transitioning from a Scheme/Racket thought process where lots of these things are fuzzy?

Small picture, now that I can grok this new implementation, I see it doesn't solve the same problem, but I think I see the general approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can obain the number of elements that match with `length . filter`. So you can here count the number of matches with:

```
compTrips :: [Int] -> [Int] -> (Int, Int)
compTrips as bs = (f as bs, f bs as)
    where f xs = length . filter id . zipWith (>) xs
```

It is usually better to return tuples to return "multiple" values. Since then these two values can have a different type, and furthermore the type checking mechansim will guarantee that you return two items.

You can perform [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) or its operator synonym [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) on the results of `getLine` to "post-process" the result:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  line1 <- map read . words <$> getLine
  line2 <- map read . words <$> getLine
  let (a, b) = compTrips line1 line2
  putStrLn (show a ++ " " ++ show b)
```

Comment: Upvoted because you paid attention to style AND implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You may perhaps do like

```
λ> :{
λ| getLine >>= return . map (read :: String -> Int) . words
λ|         >>= \l1 -> getLine
λ|         >>= return . map (read :: String -> Int) . words
λ|         >>= \l2 -> return $ zipWith (\a b -> if a > b then 1 else 0) l1 l2
λ| :}
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 1 4 2
[0,0,1,0,1]
```